# Putting hover label in my thumbnail image post WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, post

I am stuck with putting an hover label to my image from my thumbnail post using WordPress. How can I do it? I mean where should the text box for hover label from my image be? I manage to show my all 6 thumbnail image in my page using wp_query, now I want to put some hover image in every thumbnail image. Where I must input the hover image and how?

Here is my code in displaying my thumbnail images:

```
<?php

            if( $offerBlog->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <div class="row center-block">
                <?php while ( $offerBlog->have_posts() ) : $offerBlog->the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-box">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <br>
                        <br>
                    <h4> <?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Here is the output of my code:
[image: Output]

Here is what I want in every thumbnail image:

[image: Must be the output]